# ¿Cómo guardar un documento de texto plano UTF8 en Android?

Tags: java, android

Quiero guardar el contenido de un `EditText` hacia un fichero llamado `NewFile.txt` en la siguiente ruta `/storage/sdcard0/Documents/NewFile.txt` con formato `texto plano` y usando codificación `utf8`

Pero con la posibilidad de escoger el salto de linea, es decir si se quiere usar los saltos de linea de

- Windows `\r\n`
- Unix/Linux/OSX `\n`

Si es posible de la forma más eficiente.

Actualizaré con lo que voy conseguiendo:

```
public static boolean writeFileByLine(File filePath, String content) throws Exception {
    boolean result = true;

    if (!filePath.exists()) {
        result = filePath.createNewFile();
    }

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath, false)); //true for append false for new
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(content);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        writer.write(line);
        if (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            writer.newLine();
        }

    }
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La verdad es que si divides la tarea en 2 pasos suena facil:

---

## 1

Dale encoding al `BufferedWritter`, (`FileWritter` no acepta dar encoding, coje por defecto el que tiene el sistema, cosa que *toca los h#$v@s bastante*, pero puedes trampearlo con un `OutputStream` tal y como nos [muestra el maestro Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998905/java-bufferedwriter-object-with-utf-8).

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter
    (new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filePath),"UTF-8"));
```

Si no ves clara esta solución, mirate esta extensión de [`FileWritter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18911227/3850595), aunque personalmente no la veo necesaria.

---

## 2

> *Con la posibilidad de escoger el salto de linea, es decir si se quiere usar los saltos de linea*
>
> - Windows `\r\n`
> - Unix/Linux/OSX `\n`

Simplemente ve a la API de `System` y encuentra a [`System::lineSeparator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--), que como habrás adivinado por su nombre:

> *Returns the system-dependent line separator string. It always returns the same value - the initial value of the system property line.separator.
> **On UNIX systems, it returns "\n"; on Microsoft Windows systems it returns "\r\n".***

Que traducido libremente:

> Devuelve string separador especifico del sistema operativo donde se ejecute la aplicación, o sea la variable de sistema `line.separator`.
>
> **Para sistemas UNIX devuelve "`\n`" para Windows "`\r\n`"**.

Cosa que suena IDEAL para tu proposito, verdad?